# multiply filter results by adjacent column, price calculator

Tags: google-sheets, filter, multiplication

I have 2 sheets, Price calculator and Parts.
Price calculator sheet has 3 columns, Part, Qty, Cost.
I bring the Part name and Cost price in from the Parts sheet, using a filter for each column.
I want to manually enter Qty in Price calculator Qty column, and then as I do that have it multiply the adjacent Cost by the specified Qty for each Part updating the Cost result.
Is this possible on the filter results in Cost Column?

SAMPLE

```
PARTS SHEET
 
1|NAME|COST|TYPE
2|BUTTONA|$2.50|BUTTON
3|BUTTONB|$3.20|BUTTON

PRICE CALCULATOR
=filter(Parts!A2:A,Parts!C2:C="BUTTON") --THIS IS NAME
=filter(Parts!B2:B,Parts!C2:C="BUTTON") --THIS IS COST

1|NAME|QTY|COST
2|BUTTONA|  |$2.50
3|BUTTONB|  |$3.20
```

I want to manually enter QTY and have it change the COST result QTY*COST
eg if I enter 4 into B2, C3 will change to $10.00, if I then change B2 to 2 , C3 will change to $5.00, and so on for each row, is this possible?

Comment: Could you please update your question with some sample data to understand your expected result? And share your current formulas to understand your scenario better

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are two separate products, and are not fully compatible. If your question is about Sheets, the Excel tag does not apply and should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, for example if you replaced your COST formula in the price calculator sheet with

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(filter(Parts!B2:B,Parts!C2:C="BUTTON")*if(B2:B="",1,B2:B)))
```

Although maybe I'd use a Let to make it clearer:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(filter,filter(Parts!B2:B,Parts!C2:C="BUTTON"),rows,rows(filter)+1,if(row(B2:B)>rows,"",if(B2:B="",filter,filter*B2:B))))
```

[image]